# What was the purpose of the Legion of Mad Fellows?

Tags: futurama

After the Encyclopod Egg hatched ensuring a new green age, their purpose was fulfilled.  They no longer had to try and hatch or protect the Egg.

What do they do now?  They have a genetic advantage due to their telekinetic powers, but they live as hobos.  What is their new purpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They don't have a further purpose.  With the Dark Ones defeated, they are as soldiers after a war is won.  They're no longer obligated to help the Encyclopods or anyone.  So they're free to do what they want.  Presumably they would continue to assist the Encyclopods in their mission of safekeeping endangered species.